# How to extract first record _time value in a flux query?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I am attempting to extract the first time value of a query in order to use it with the function `experimental.alignTime`. I have tried various options, but none have worked. Here is an example of the last solution I tried:

```
import "experimental"

firstTime = from(bucket: "kW_Generale")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "DMED_Generale")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "1_kWatts")
  |> first(column: "_time")
  |> limit(n: 1)

from(bucket: "kW_Generale")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "DMED_Generale")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "1_kWatts")
  |> window(every: 1d)
  |> experimental.alignTime(alignTo: firstTime._time)
```